# In page navigation being hidden by navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 with `fixed on top navbar`.

I am trying to do in page navigation but the content is being hidden by the navbar.

Fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/df8tb/504/)

Any alternative solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it and put the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/df8tb/505/)

Just substracted 150 from the animate's scrollTop property.

```
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 150
}, 1000);
```

Comment: aweosme, how do I make the li class active based on the scrolled para ?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you need to provide a padding-top of same or more height, as that of navbar

say: in this case: give

```
p {padding-top: 60px !important;}
```

important was needed as you gave inline css, or you can remove padding from inline css directly and simply give padding to **p** tag or but to specific give a common class name to this divs and give it padding-top value, or your p tag at other place can get affected..

use proper selecters, simply